# Example of non-abelian partially ordered group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, lattice-orders

What is a simple example of a non-abelian partially ordered group?

Comment: Question in the title and question in the question's body to not match.

Comment: $S_3$ is nonabelian and if we give it the trivial ordering (every element is $\leq$ every other element) we're done. If you want a nontrivial ordering, let $x \leq y$ if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.

Comment: @Julien Clancy: This is not a partial order, because it is not an antisymmetric relation.

Comment: @GejzaJenča See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group

Comment: @Julien Clancy I referenced to the second part of your comment. "To have the same sign" is clearly a nontrivial equivalence relation, so it is _not_ antisymmetric.

Comment: @GejzaJenča I don't see any requirement of antisymmetry in the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: @JulienClancy One has to dig deeper: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order#Formal_definition

Comment: @GejzaJenča I saw that earlier and assumed for some reason that it was inconvenient to have antisymmetry in partially ordered groups. But I'll trust your group knowledge over mine and thanks for clarifying.

Comment: More info on Math Overflow at [What's a non-abelian totally ordered group?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4011/whats-a-non-abelian-totally-ordered-group), especially in Rolfsen's [Ordered Groups and Topology](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~rolfsen/papers/luminynotes/lum.pdf).  The simplest example of a nonabelian group with a _total_ order appears to be the free group on two generators, but the proof is not obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All strictly increasing functions $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, equipped with composition as the group operation and with the usual partial order given by $f\leq g$ if and only if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$. Note that this is a lattice ordered group.

Comment: @Gejza, Very nice example. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Free group over two generators $F(a,b)$ is non-abelian and is poset w.r.t dictionary order induced by $a<b$.

Yeah although, if you wanted a non total partial ordered group, than Gejza's example is best.